# HTML form submission(POST req) to the server should return a dynamic HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, handlebars.js, ejs

How do I get the server-side(in NodeJS and Express) to return a new HTML page after receiving a post request?

- Let's say the HTML page a several fields and each needs to be checked (which could be done using Javascript) in the HTML page itself.
- But after submitting the form, the server-side does some heavy calculation (let's say it take 5 seconds on complete it, maybe more).
- And then the server-side returns a new HTML page which highlights results of all the input fields individually.
- I can't use a static HTML page to be returned since there can be many outcomes and I want the HTML page (send by the server) to dynamically adjust based on the calculation done by the server.

q1. How can I create this dynamic HTML page on the server-side?

q2. How do I show the user a loading screen when server-side is performing the calculations?

Correct me if I am wrong

a1. I believe I can create some sort of static HTML template with EJS/JADE/PUG/HANDLEBARS and then pass the result of the calculations and let JS Script(in HTML) handle how it is displayed.

a2. I do no have an idea about it now.

Comment: You can mark my answer as accepted if it solved your issue

Answer (score 1):

You can make an ajax call to your server & return success / error data / calculations in json format

Then use this json to add dynamic html content on your page using client side javascript

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/admin/login',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {'key':'value'},
    beforeSend: function(){
      // show loader
    },
    success: function(response) {
       // hide loader
       // add dynamic html to dom from here
    });
```

Hope this helps